# Any feedback on using CodeceptJS with Sencha ExtJS for testing Automation

Tags: testing, extjs, automation, codeceptjs

Hi I need to automate testing of an app made with Sencha ExtJS. Is codeceptJS a viable options.

I am concerned how i could work with buttons which are icons. Also ids are dynamically generated in Sencha.

Comment: Why dont you use [Sencha Test](https://www.sencha.com/products/test/)?

Comment: I would suggest Siesta (https://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query to access your components.

For example you could use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemId')` or `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('xtype')` depending on your application.

if you need access to the DOM node you can use `component.el.dom` where component is an ExtJS Component (e.g. selected using ComponentQuery)